# Redirect to new domain with .htaccess

Tags: htaccess

I am changing the domain of my website.

But, I am struggling with the domain redirection. I need to implement this wildcard redirection.

So that I visit.

`https://www.oldomain.com/page1`

It should go to

`https://newdomain.com/page1`

Note: The new domain is without www.

Can anyone help me how to implement this?

Comment: Have you tried anything? Is `newdomain.com` currently pointing to the same place as `www.oldomain.com`?

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.oldomain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```